# SAXParseException when using restassured

Tags: rest-assured, saxparser

I am trying to verify a XML response with rest-assured like this:

```
.then().body("some.xml.path", is("abc"));
```

However, what I get is a SAXParseException:

> DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.]

Response starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cXML.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.021/cXML.dtd">
<cXML ...
```

Why am I getting this exception? What should I change?

I am using version 3.2.0 of rest-assured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question has been answered [here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/765#issuecomment-258785174). In short, the answer describes to use `disableLoadingOfExternalDtd()` to have RestAssured ignore the Document Type Definition in your XML.

Normally, the DTD would describe (using the external definition) the structural layout of the element defined as `cXML`.

Comment: Thanks! However, I would like to know why this error occurs. Is there something wrong with my XML? Or is it just a bug of rest-assured?

Comment: I had to add allowDocTypeDeclaration(true) as well to make it work.